# Using a global array between files

Tags: javascript, arrays, plugins, cocoascript

I'm currently writing a Sketch Plugin and I'm trying to store data inside an global array. In the *copy.sketchscript* the data is generated, and in *paste.sketchscript* I'm trying to retrieve the array data. However, when I log the variable, it returns empty. What can I do to update the array data properly so that every function can access it?

Here's my code.

**library/common.js**

```
var verticalRulers = new Array; // global?

function copyVertical(context) {
    var doc = context.document

    var target = [[doc currentPage] currentArtboard] || [doc currentPage]
    var countVertical = [[target verticalRulerData] numberOfGuides]

    for(var i=0; i < countVertical; i++) {
        var thisRuler = [[target verticalRulerData] guideAtIndex:i]
        verticalRulers.push(thisRuler);
    }
}

function pasteVertical(context) {
    var doc = context.document
    var target = [[doc currentPage] currentArtboard] || [doc currentPage]

    for(i = 0; i < verticalRulers.length; i++) {
        var thisRuler = verticalRulers[i];

        [[target verticalRulerData] addGuideWithValue: thisRuler]
    }
}
```

copy.sketchscript

```
@import 'library/common.js'

function onRun(context) {
    verticalRulers = copyVertical(context);
    log(verticalRulers) // return right data from variable;
}
```

paste.sketchscript

```
@import 'library/common.js'

function onRun(context) {
    pasteVertical(context);
    log(verticalRulers); // returns an empty array
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with any of the technologies, and I couldn't easily find documentation on what the heck `@import` does, so... how exactly does `@import 'library/common.js'` work? Does it just insert the contents of that script at the top? If so, you're re-creating the array each time, so of course it's going to be empty.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist You might be right... http://bohemiancoding.com/sketch/support/developer/02-common-tasks/04.html Any other idea how I can achieve what I want?